# Settings values not showing up. Cache issue?

Tags: database, settings, administer

I am experiencing a strange issue with my CiviCRM (4.7.3) installation on Joomla (3.4.8) with MySQLi 5.6.28-76.1-log and PHP 5.6.18.

If I change some of the settings in one of the administration pages, they are correctly updated on the database, but if I get back to that page I don't see the setting anymore. It seems like values for the settings pages are not retrieved correctly from the database.

It's seems like a cache problem, but I've tried to clean the followings to not avail:
- browser cache (tried different browsers as well)
- joomla cache
- siteground supercacher

Problem still there. Any ideas?

First screenshot is from a working CiviCRM installation (http://sandbox.joomla.civicrm.org/). If you check any of the settings pages (ie. Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Locations) you can see that the options have values according to what is in the database. Radio buttons are correctly valorised. If you change the option, save and get back to the page you can see the option you choose. This is the normal behaviour.

[image: First screenshot: working CiviCRM]

Second screenshot is from our CiviCRM installation (http://omphalospg.org/). If you check any of the settings pages (ie. Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Locations) you can see that some of the options don’t have values according to what is in the database. Radio buttons in particular are not correctly valorised. If you change the option, save and get back to the page you cannot see the option you choose, even though the option is correctly saved in the database. This is not a correct behaviour.

[image: Second screenshot: not working CiviCRM]

Comment: Two more tests:
1) I have made a fresh new installation of Joomla and CiviCRM on the same server and the issue is still the same.
2) I have made a fresh new installation of Drupal and CiviCRM and the issue is not present

It seems that the issue is related to CiviCRM on Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed the problem carefully and found that it is caused by the jSGCache plugin that comes preinstalled on all Joomla sites installed via Softaculous. When the plugin is enabled, it adds a special cookie to to prevent caching the admin panel. This seems to conflict with CiviCRM and results in the problem you reported.

Comment: You can accept your own answer!